# Regex should allow German Umlauts in C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am using following regular expression:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+(?:[\._-äöüÄÖÜß][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_UsernameFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
```

Now I want to improve it the way it will allow German Umlauts(äöüÄÖÜß).

Comment: No, it's not working. In fact my original expression is @"^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$". and I need to allow German Umlauts also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you added German letters to your regex, it will only be possible to use German letters in the first word.

You need to put the letters into the last character class:

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+)*$"
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B._-%5D%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F%5D%2B%29*%24&i=gem%C3%A4%C3%9F-%C3%9Cberlieferung)

Also, note that `_-ä` creates a range inside a character class that matches a lot more than just a `_`, `-` and `ä` (and does not even match `-` as it is not present in the range).

Note that if you validate on the server side only, and want to match any Unicode letters, you may also consider using

```
@"^[\p{L}0-9]+(?:[._-][\p{L}0-9]+)*$"
```

Where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter. Another way to write `[\p{L}0-9]` would be `[^\W_]`, but in .NET, it would also match all Unicode digits while `0-9` will only match ASCII digits.

Comment: In fact my original expression is @"^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$". and I need to allow German Umlauts also. For your given expression 
 following name does not worked : ömus9äüÄÖÜß

Comment: [`ömus9äüÄÖÜß` is matched with the above regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Za-z0-9%c3%a4%c3%b6%c3%bc%c3%84%c3%96%c3%9c%c3%9f%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b._-%5d%5bA-Za-z0-9%c3%a4%c3%b6%c3%bc%c3%84%c3%96%c3%9c%c3%9f%5d%2b%29*%24&i=%c3%b6mus9%c3%a4%c3%bc%c3%84%c3%96%c3%9c%c3%9f).

Comment: @DipakAkhade: `[A-Za-z0-9]` is an alphanumeric matching character class. The characters can be just added to it to match more than ASCII - just as I showed in my answer. Please check your full code, since my *regex* matches what you need.

Answer (score 0):

replace `[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]` with `[\w]`. `\w` already contains Umlauts.

Comment: Yes, but `\w` also matches underscores. Besides, it will only work on server side, since on the client side, the expression is parsed as an ECMAScript pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This works better i just modified somebody else his code who posted it on Stackoverflow. this works good for German language encoding.
I just added this code (c >= 'Ä' && c <= 'ä') and now it is working more towards my needs. Not all German letters are supported you need to create your own (c >= 'Ö' && c <= 'ö') type to add the letters u are having a issue with.

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(this string str)
    {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (char c in str)
        {                 
             if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'Ö' && c <= 'ö') || (c >= 'Ü' && c <= 'ü') || (c >= 'Ä' && c <= 'ä') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == ' ')
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return clean(sb);
    }
```